# Multi-format word counter

Tags: python, tkinter

I wrote a simple word-counter in Python a while ago, capable of processing DOCX, XLSX, TXT, and some PDF files. Now I gave it a simple GUI - this is my first tkinter program ever. What do you think?

```
import openpyxl
import docx2txt
import PyPDF2
import tkinter
from tkinter import filedialog


def excel_counter(filename):
    count = 0
    wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(filename)
    for sheet in wb:
        for row in sheet:
            for cell in row:
                text = str(cell.value)
                if text != "None":
                    word_list = text.split()
                    count += len(word_list)
    return count


def pdf_counter(filename):
    pdf_word_count = 0
    pdfFileObj = open(filename, "rb")
    pdfReader = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(pdfFileObj)
    number_of_pages = pdfReader.getNumPages() - 1
    for page in range(0, number_of_pages + 1):
        page_contents = pdfReader.getPage(page - 1)
        raw_text = page_contents.extractText()
        text = raw_text.encode('utf-8')
        page_word_count = len(text.split())
        pdf_word_count += page_word_count
    return pdf_word_count


def uploadaction(event=None):
    root = tkinter.Tk()
    root.destroy()
    filename = filedialog.askopenfilename()
    return filename


def wordcounter(file):
    extension = file.split(".")[-1]
    if extension == "xlsx":
        current_count = excel_counter(file)
        return current_count
    if extension == "docx":
        text = docx2txt.process(file)
        current_count = len(text.split())
        return current_count
    if extension == "txt":
        f = open(file, "r")
        text = f.read()
        current_count = len(text.split())
        return current_count
    if extension == "pdf":
        pdf_word_count = pdf_counter(file)
        return pdf_word_count


window = tkinter.Tk()
wordcount = wordcounter(uploadaction())
label = tkinter.Label(text=f"Word Count: {wordcount}")
label.pack()
window.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One suggestion is to simplify your top-level function by taking
advantage of a library and using a data structure to eliminate conditional logic.

```
import pathlib

def wordcounter(file_path):
    # Let a built-in library solve this problem.
    extension = pathlib.Path(file_path).suffix

    # Hold the counter functions in a data structure.
    # You'll need to create a couple of these.
    counters = {
        'xlsx': excel_counter,
        'docx': word_counter,
        'txt': txt_counter,
        'pdf': pdf_counter,
    }

    # Then just do what you want directly rather than checking conditions.
    return counters[extension](file_path)
```

Another observation is that your counter functions are duplicating the word
counting logic. Such duplication is often a signal that there are refactoring
possibilities: more specifically, the thing being duplicated might belong in
its own function. If we do that, you'll need to convert your current counter
functions (which take a path and return an integer) into reader functions (take a path
and yield chunks of text). Such a refactor is illustrated for `excel_reader`.
And those changes will imply a few simple adjustments in `wordcounter`.

```
def count_words(reader, file_path):
    n = 0
    for text in reader(file_path):
        n += len(text.split())
    return n

def excel_reader(file_path):
    wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(filename)
    for sheet in wb:
        for row in sheet:
            for cell in row:
                # Your current logic.
                text = str(cell.value)
                if text != "None":
                    yield text

                # I've never used openpxl, but a quick internet
                # search suggests that this is more robust conditional
                # check to filter out empty cells.
                if cell.value is not None:
                    yield str(cell.value)
```